# Is multi-tenancy possible/practical with Google OAuth2?

Tags: google-oauth

Our SaaS platform allows customers to use Google SSO (OAuth) to authenticate. We use a pure OAuth flow, since we support other OAuth identity providers, using the same mechanism.

We also allow customers to attach their own custom domain. But when configuring Google OAuth credentials, we must provide one or more "Authorised JavaScript origins", from where the OAuth flow can initiate.

Is there any way for us to support both custom domains and Google SSO for our customers? It's not practical that we manually update the Authorized origins every time a customer choses to add a custom domain. And I don't think there is a programmatic way to do this.

Any advice?